# Next.js pass NODE_ENV to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

I'm building a React SSR App, using Next.js.

I want to be able to access the NODE_ENV on the client side, as this will tell my app which API endpoints to use.

I'm struggling to find a decent approach for this. I'd like to define the NODE_ENV as a window variable when I first render the page on the server, and then in my helper function where I make the API call, I would check if the code is being called on the server or the client, and using the `window` or `process.env` objects as required.

Does anyone have a good solution for such a problem? It must be a common issue but I can't find any good solutions.

Comment: [Have you tried using the `DefinePlugin`?](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/159#issuecomment-268476743-permalink)

Comment: You can include that to window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialState || {})};

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### Using next/config:

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import getConfig from 'next/config'

const {publicRuntimeConfig} = getConfig()
const {API_URL} = publicRuntimeConfig

export default class extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps () {
    // fetch(`${API_URL}/some-path`)
    return {}
  }

  render () {
    return <div>
            The API_URL is {API_URL}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Reference: [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-universal-configuration-runtime)

### Another option - you can include it in webpack configuration (using dotenv-webpack dependency):

```js
require('dotenv').config()

const path = require('path')
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack')

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || []

    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,

      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true
      })
    ]

    return config
  }
}
```

Reference: [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-dotenv)

---

### Yet another option - using babel plugin to import the variable towards the entire app:

env-config.js

```
const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  'process.env.BACKEND_URL': prod ? 'https://api.example.com' : 'https://localhost:8080'
}
```

.babelrc.js

```
const env = require('./env-config.js')

module.exports = {
  presets: ['next/babel'],
  plugins: [['transform-define', env]]
}
```

index.js

```
export default () => (
  <div>Loading data from { process.env.BACKEND_URL }</div>
)
```

Reference: [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-universal-configuration)

Comment: I think the last one is the best solution, Thanks!

Comment: Is it required for the last `NextJS` version?

Comment: @SalahAdDin it depends on your system design. if you combine backend (e.g: nodejs) and frontend NextJS in one project or using SSR from NextJS then env configuration still required, and if you want to pass it to frontend you can use the above ways. Otherwise, like using static export NextJS you don't need this one.

Answer (score 10):

## Using Next's build-time configuration

@DarrylR already mentioned using `next.config.js` and
Next's [runtime configuration](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#runtime-configuration),
but you can also use Next's [build-time configuration](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#build-time-configuration).

This lets you put the `process.env.XXXX` right into the code (as shown in step 3 below), and you don't have to import anything. However, if you env variables should be set both when you build locally with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) and when you deploy to [ZEIT Now](https://zeit.co/now), I don't know if you can keep them in just one file using this method (see step 2 below).

The runtime configuration docs suggest you normally want to use build-time configuration:

> **Warning:** Generally you want to use build-time configuration to provide your configuration. The reason for this is that runtime configuration adds rendering / initialization overhead and is **incompatible with [automatic prerendering](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#automatic-prerendering).**

---

Steps:

### 1. Set `NODE_ENV` for build process

#### 1.1 Using [ZEIT Now](https://zeit.co/now)

If you deploy using ZEIT Now, you can set the [env variables used at build time](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration#build.env) in `now.json`:

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "build": {
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }
}
```

#### 1.2 When running locally (optional)

If you want `NODE_ENV` to be set when running locally as well, this will not be set by `now.json`.
However you can set it in other ways, such as:

```
$ NODE_ENV=production npm run build
```

or change the build script in `package.json` to

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production next build"
```

You can of course also set `NODE_ENV` for other scripts than build if you want that.

### 2. Make Next inline value of `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Add this to the `next.config.js` as described [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#runtime-configuration):

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV
  }
};
```

### 3. Use in code

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  console.log("In production")
} else {
  console.log("Not in production")
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but NODE_ENV is not allow in next.config.js in my case : https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/env-key-not-allowed.md

Comment: In step 1 and 2 I try to explain how to set it up. Can you explain what part of it is missing or confusing? (Actually, not sure if you mean me or the first comment.)

Answer (score 8):

Another Easy solution:

create 2 files on root folder:

```
.env.development
.env.production
```

inside add variables as you need, for example in .env.development file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV="development"
```

and in .env.production file:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV="production"
```

Then use it for example:

```
console.log('Version: ', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV);
```

Answer (score 8):

Since Next.js 9.4, NextJs has now built-in support for environment variables, which allows you to do the following using .env files:

An example .env.local:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=myuser
DB_PASS=mypassword
```

If you want to expose the env variables to the client, you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` for example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_PORT=4000
```

If you want to use the variable, you can use it like this: `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_PORT`

For the documentation see [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables)